# Ruby rails how to receive the http post data from iOS post request

Tags: ios, ruby, networking, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4.0.2. I try to send one http post request from iOS to Ruby Rails. And rails need to respond to iOS. But I really can not figure out how rails to receive this post request, and get the data from this post request. I can not get the feedback from rails. The iOS show noting......from server.

- iOS Coding:

  ```
  // Get image name from user input.
  NSString *imageNameString = [self.imageNameTextField text];

  // Get URL.
  NSString *urlString = [self.urlTextField text];
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

  // Init Request.
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
  [request setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
  [request setHTTPBody:[imageNameString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

  // Init operation queue.
  NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

  // Connect server.
  [NSURLConnection
   sendAsynchronousRequest:request
   queue:queue
   completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

       if ([data length] > 0 && connectionError == nil) {

       NSMutableDictionary *jsonDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                          options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                         error:nil];

               // Debug:
               NSLog(@"MY JSON DATA = %@", jsonDic);

       } else if ([data length] == 0) { // No data from server.

               NSLog(@"No data from server.");

       } else { // There is one Error.

               NSLog(@"There is one Error.");

       }
   }];
  ```

---

Ruby Rails Coding:

---

```
    def answer_ios
        image_image = params[0]
        respond_to do |format|
            message = {:content => image_image, :msg => 'this is one post request test'}
            format.json {render :json => message}
        end
    end
```

Comment: you need to look at the `params` reaching the controller `action` to know how to respond to it, and to know if the IOS app is sending the right `payload`

Comment: I have check the rails about params reaching the controller action. They all use the params to get the post body. But the parameter of 'params[]' is the name of elem of html. But for iOS, I just hope to use post method to send one message. How should I set the name for this message like my code above?

Comment: in your controller action (`answer_ios`) add this `Rails.logger.info "This is params: #{params}"` then send a post request from your IOS app to the rails app to see what it received as the `JSON` payload that would make your task easier